# PHP Contact Form is not submitting to email or redirecting new URL

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've been worked with contact forms before, yet this one just isn't submitting to my email. I'm also trying to implement a redirect URL to /contact.php

The problem with the code is: it isn't being received by my email. My question is: What is not allowing the contact form to get through to email?

```
<form id='contactus' action='index.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
   <fieldset>
     <div class="first-row">
       <label for="name">Your Name</label>
       <input type='text' class="input-large" name='name' id='name' value=''  placeholder="Your Name"  />
       <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
       <input type='text' class="input-large" name='phone' id='phone' value=''  placeholder="Phone Number"  />
     </div>
     <div class="second-row">
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type='text' class="input-large" name='email' id='email' value=''  placeholder="Email Address" />
    </div>
     <div class="second-row">
       <label for="business">Business</label>
       <input type='text' class="input-large" name='business' id='business' value=''  placeholder="Business" />
     </div>
    <label style="margin-left: 20px;" for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea rows="10" class="input-xlarge" cols="50" name='message' placeholder="Message" id='message'></textarea>
    <div class="clearfix"></div> /* Sorry I'm using Bootstrap */
    <div><input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" name='Submit' value='Submit' />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/php">                      
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $to = "hello@geniusghost.com";
  $subject = "Genius Ghost Contact Form";
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $business = $_POST['business'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $body = "From: $name\n Phone Number: $phone\n E-Mail: $email\n Business: $business\n\n Message:\n $message";
  mail($to, $subject, $body);
} 
?>
</script>
```

Help me! I know you all probably get these questions all the time..

Comment: Change `name='Submit'` to `name='submit'` Variables and form elements are case-sensitive. Actually, this is more an answer than a comment. Plus, lose the `<script type="text/php">` and `</script>`

Comment: Ummmmmm, `<script type="text/php">`? By the way, you need to clarify your question, what code is part of what file?

Comment: Plus, you're going to have a rude awakening. Let's see who figures it out; *I have*.

Comment: Changed the submit, but still not receiving it in the email itself. I know the script type is wonky, but it was crashing the entire page before otherwise. It's actually in a .php file. index.php

Comment: [`See my answer, tested`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22623875/) @Cee complete with explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$_POST['submit']` should have a capital "**S**" as your submit button's name is "**Submit**".

Also, you don't need to wrap PHP in `<script>` tags - only `<?php ... ?>`

**Code:**

```
<form id='contactus' action='index.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <fieldset >
        <div class="first-row">
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
            <input type='text' class="input-large" name='name' id='name' value=''  placeholder="Your Name"  />
            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input type='text' class="input-large" name='phone' id='phone' value=''  placeholder="Phone Number"  />
        </div>
        <div class="second-row">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type='text' class="input-large" name='email' id='email' value=''  placeholder="Email Address" />
        </div>
        <div class="second-row">
            <label for="business">Business</label>
            <input type='text' class="input-large" name='business' id='business' value=''  placeholder="Business" />
        </div>

        <label style="margin-left: 20px;" for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea rows="10" class="input-xlarge" cols="50" name='message' placeholder="Message" id='message'></textarea>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> /* Sorry I'm using Bootstrap */
        <div>
            <input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" name='Submit' value='Submit' />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "hello@geniusghost.com";
    $subject = "Genius Ghost Contact Form";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $business = $_POST['business'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $body = "From: $name\n Phone Number: $phone\n E-Mail: $email\n Business: $business\n\n Message:\n $message";

    mail($to, $subject, $body);
} 
?>
```

Let me know if you have any issues!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change `name='Submit'` to `name='submit'`. Variables and form elements are case-sensitive.

Plus, lose the `<script type="text/php">` and `</script>`

Using `$body = "From: $name\n` would have resulted in an improperly formed [`mail header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for the `From:` part of it, and you will never would have been able to make a direct reply to the person who emailed you.

Fixed/changed and tested.

Sidenote: If you're using this code in one file, use `action=""` instead of `action='index.php'`

(*There's more on that under my footnotes*)

```
<form id='contactus' action='index.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
   <fieldset >
   <div class="first-row">
    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
    <input type='text' class="input-large" name='name' id='name' value=''  placeholder="Your Name"  />

        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type='text' class="input-large" name='phone' id='phone' value=''  placeholder="Phone Number"  />
    </div>
    <div class="second-row">
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type='text' class="input-large" name='email' id='email' value=''  placeholder="Email Address" />
    </div>
     <div class="second-row">
    <label for="business">Business</label>
    <input type='text' class="input-large" name='business' id='business' value=''  placeholder="Business" />
    </div>

        <label style="margin-left: 20px;" for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea rows="10" class="input-xlarge" cols="50" name='message' placeholder="Message" id='message'></textarea>
    <div class="clearfix"></div> /* Sorry I'm using Bootstrap */
    <div><input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" name='submit' value='Submit' />
    </div>
     </fieldset>
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "hello@geniusghost.com";
$subject = "Genius Ghost Contact Form";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From: $name<$email>\r\n";
$body = "From: $name<$email>\r\n Phone Number: $phone\n E-Mail: $email\n Business: $business\n\n Message:\n $message";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

If you don't want the form to appear after submission, should this be the case, use the following:

Sidenote: This will only work if PHP is on top of HTML and used as a single file, should you want to use this method.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $to = "hello@geniusghost.com";
        $subject = "Genius Ghost Contact Form";
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $business = $_POST['business'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $headers = "From: $name<$email>\r\n";

        $body = "From: $name<$email>\r\n Phone Number: $phone\n E-Mail: $email\n Business: $business\n\n Message:\n $message";

        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
        echo "Thank you.";
        echo "<a href='http://www.example.com/home.php'>Click here</a> to return to the home page.";
        exit();
} 
?>

<form id='contactus' action='' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
   <fieldset >
   <div class="first-row">
    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
    <input type='text' class="input-large" name='name' id='name' value=''  placeholder="Your Name"  />

        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type='text' class="input-large" name='phone' id='phone' value=''  placeholder="Phone Number"  />
    </div>
    <div class="second-row">
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type='text' class="input-large" name='email' id='email' value=''  placeholder="Email Address" />
    </div>
     <div class="second-row">
    <label for="business">Business</label>
    <input type='text' class="input-large" name='business' id='business' value=''  placeholder="Business" />
    </div>

        <label style="margin-left: 20px;" for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea rows="10" class="input-xlarge" cols="50" name='message' placeholder="Message" id='message'></textarea>
    <div class="clearfix"></div> /* Sorry I'm using Bootstrap */
    <div><input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" name='submit' value='Submit' />
    </div>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```